# menuToggle button hides when logging in from loginPage

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I'have used menu template from ionic, I change it according to my need of app and when I'm logging in the app from login or signup page to my home page where menuToggle button is defined, but when I'm not able to see the menu button.

**Code for My HomePage:**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>Dashboard</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    Hello
</ion-content>
```

**My loginpage:**

```
<ion-header>
     <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
        <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar> 
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div ion-fixed class="login_wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./assets/images/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="login_content">
            <form #submitForm="ngForm">
                <ion-list ngFormModel="LoginForm">
                    <ion-item class="logintext">
                        <ion-label class="login_label" stacked>Username</ion-label>
                        <ion-input class="login_input" type="email" name="username" [(ngModel)]="uname"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item class="logintext">
                        <ion-label class="login_label" stacked>Password</ion-label>
                        <ion-input class="login_input" type="password" name="email" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <div class="submitbtn">
                        <button ion-button type="submit" class="sbtbtn" (click)="signIn($event)" color="light" full> SignIn </button>
                    </div>
                </ion-list>
            </form>
            <div class="submitbtn">
                <button ion-button type="submit" class="sbtbtn" (tap)="openRegister()" color="light" full> SignUp </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**I'm just using to load my homepage**

```
signIn(e) {
    console.log("SignIn Btn Clicked");
    this.navCtrl.push("Home");
}
```

Now when I'm loading only homepage then I can see my menu button but when I navigate from login page menu disappeared.

Comment: I think what you want is `this.navCtrl.setRoot("Home")`

Comment: No man i can not do that because i'have already set it in my app.component.ts as  ` setRoot(page.component) `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got it solved by changing ion-navbar to ion-toolbar**

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar hideBackButton="true">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Dashboard</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Now i'm able to see the menu at my homepage after login and signup in ionic2 ios app

Comment: I think this is not the right way to do it. By pushing the view instead of using `this.navCtrl.setRoot("Home")` after logging in, the user would be able to press the physical back button from the HomePage, and will go to the LoginPage again. I've never seen that behavior on a mobile app.

Comment: I'm developing it for ios app.

Comment: Good point. Then it should be the same from the end user perspective. Could you please add that to your answer? It may help some other SO users facing the same issue (but letting them know that it wouldn't be the right way to do it for Android apps)

Comment: Yah i did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy too, but the thing I found to do, was to add the menu code to the same page as the one you are on. (Well, so far anyway). I'm sure my project will go beyond this in the future.

For example:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
     <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu" ></ion-icon>
      </button>
     </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title><img alt="logo" height="40"  src="./assets/images/logo.png" ></ion-title>

    <ion-buttons right >
     <button (click)="openModal()"  icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="headset" ></ion-icon>
     </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

  <ion-menu [content]="content" persistent="true" type="overlay">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
          Menu
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content >
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item (click)="gotohome()">
          Home
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item (click)="ChangeLanguagePageclick()">
          Set Language
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-nav [root]="TabsPage" #content></ion-nav>


<ion-content >
Normal contents
</ion-content>
```

In this page, TabsPage is my root document, so you'll have to adjust that.

After many tries, I've also updated this so that it works in iOS as well.